# x509 Certificate may not have access rights for the private key

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to import a certificate for user by my application. This works on server 2012 and windows 10 however on older operating systems like windows 7 and server 2008 r2 the import doesn't seem to work correctly. Some of the work is done by a helper class which copies the certificate and assigns the permission.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(certLocation), "test_cert.pfx");
//Create the certificate and import it
_cert = new X509Certificate2();
_cert.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509CertHelper.CopyCertToStore(_cert, StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
X509CertHelper.AddAccessToCertificate(_cert, Environment.UserName);
```

I add a permission call to set the permission which appears to work correctly. However when looking in the certificate manager and choosing from the context menu "Manage Private Keys" give me two different results. On newer operating systems the permissions dialog correctly shows the newly added permissions by the code but on older ones I only get a cryptic error, and when I start my service I get the following error.

**It is likely that certificate 'CN=test' may
 not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key.**

[image]

Any ideas about what might be going wrong or extra steps for older operating systems? I recently ran updates on this machine (Server 2008 R2) as I assumed that might be the issue. I also do need to do this in code. The following code sets the permission.

```
private static void AddAccessToCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert, string user)
{
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        if (rsa != null)
        {
            string keyfilepath =
                FindKeyLocation(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName);

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(keyfilepath + "\\" +
                rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName);

            FileSecurity fs = file.GetAccessControl();

            NTAccount account = new NTAccount(user);
            fs.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

            file.SetAccessControl(fs);
        }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `CurrentUser` store for user certificates. There is no need to install user certificates in machine store.

Comment: The cert can be used by a service or run in console mode. Why is there a problem with using the machine store?